# Can't Run ngrok.exe wit ahk

Tags: autohotkey, ngrok

I'm trying to start up ngrok to automate some process with ahk e.g. I want to start up ngrok type `ngrok tcp -region eu 1234` but when I try the code `Run, ngrok.exe, C:\Users\\Desktop` as soon as the window appears it disappears

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to pass `C:\Users\\Desktop` as a parameter to `ngrok.exe` using the `Run` command, try instead

```
Run, ngrok.exe C:\Users\\Desktop
```

or

```
Run, "ngrok.exe" C:\Users\\Desktop
```

From [the Docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm):

> ### Run
>
> Runs an external program
>
> ```
> Run, Target [, WorkingDir, Options, OutputVarPID]
> ```

Please note that passing parameters past the `Target` section of the `Run` command does not pass those parameters to the target. Instead, it triggers either the `WorkingDir`, `Options`, or `OutputVarPID` parts of the `Run` command.

So, we instead include these parameters in the `Target` section of the `Run` command itself as seen above.